# BIOS password reset

Tags: bios

We are working with various compliance companies for our systems (which are mostly Windows 7, Intel, custom made). One such company might soon be implementing BIOS passwords as a compliance.

Pretty sure I know the answer, but short of manually going to each PC and setting a BIOS password, is there a utility out there that can make this easier? As mentioned before, most of our systems are very similar.

Comment: Do your systems have vPro Out-Of-Band management with KVMoIP?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented BIOS passwords (and configuration) on most of our systems over last 2 years so this is from experience. With exception of Lenovo (password is set manually by technician), configuration and password is scripted during computer setup (Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager 2012 R2). However there is nothing stopping you from scripting it post-install with your favourite configuration management tool.

- Lenovo - Password MUST be set by human input or preset in factory
  upon order. It cannot be set by tools, only changed. WMI interface is
  documented https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht100612
- HP - Passwords can be set using tools in BCU http://www8.hp.com/us/en/ads/clientmanagement/drivers-bios.html?jumpid=va_r11260_go_clientmanagement_sdm
- Dell - Passwords can be set using CCTK/DCCS http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/enterprise-client/w/wiki/7431.dell-client-command-suite
- Fujitsu - Passwords can be set using DeskView http://support.ts.fujitsu.com/download/Showdescription.asp?SoftwareGUID=9623C7A0-8C3D-41A8-A54F-8CCF505FC068
- Panasonic (ToughBook, ToughPad) - configuration tool exists but is
  not public. Quite unstable and lacking documentation.
- Intel Desktop Boards - Passwords can be set using custom BIOS update generated by Intel Integrator Toolkit
  http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-boards-software-integrator-toolkit.html
  I have not widely tested this (last boards are being retired).

If you meant Intel as only CPU manufacturer, YMMV. Most (if not all) generic Asian motherboard manufacturers (Asus, MSI, GigaByte etc) do not have configuration tools (every tool above is vendor specific). If you have Intel vPro implemented (very few generic motherboards implement it), you can use it for white boxes (and Lenovos) but it will be a clickfest. Otherwise you're out of luck and have to visit each workstation.